# Acessing elements in jagged arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, jagged-arrays

I am starting to write a recursion backtrack maze system printed in console but I already stumble in a trivial problem, I can't set the lines from my grid structure as you can see below:

```js
console.log("Teste de Labirinto - Recursive Backtracking")

let grid = []
let cells = []

const width = 8
const height = 10

for (let i = 0; i < width; i++){
    cells.push(".")
}
for (let j = 0; j < height; j++){
    grid.push(cells)
}

function printMaze(){
    let line = " "
    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            line += " " + grid[j][i] + "  "
        }
        console.log(line)
        line = " "
    }
}

function createMazeBorder() {
    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                grid[j][i] = "X"
            }
        }
    }
}

createMazeBorder()
printMaze()
```

How can I create a wall of "X" in my grid? I tried all the "ifs" as possible and swap the "i" and "j", widht, height, still can't do it... Thank you for the time.

Comment: I don't understand your question. From what I'm seeing you already print a wall of X's in the grid's left side.

Comment: I solved it, should I edit, aswer my own question or delete it? It is my first question, thx for the time

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it so other know is resolved. Maybe it could help someone.

Comment: Thx, I will do it... Anyway my problem was in the grid.push(cells), where cells were not instanciate again, so all of my cells inside grid got the same reference

Answer (score 2):

Well, solved it, it was not possible to create the walls because all my cells got the same reference, there is the code:

```js
console.log("Teste de Labirinto - Recursive Backtracking")

let grid = []

const width = 8
const height = 10

for (let j = 0; j < height; j++){
    let cells = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < width; i++){
        cells.push(".")
    }
    grid.push(cells)
}

function printMaze(){
    let line = " "
    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            line += " " + grid[j][i] + "  "
        }
        console.log(line)
        line = " "
    }
}

function createMazeBorder() {
    for (let j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            if(j == 0 || i == 0 || j == height-1 || i == width-1) {
                grid[j][i] = "X"
            }
        }
    }
}

createMazeBorder()
printMaze()
```